# Task Scheduler and Mapped Drive Invalid Disk Specification

Tags: network-shares, task-scheduler

I have a task in Task Scheduler to run a batch file that resides on a local hard drive.

The batch file simply runs XCopy to copy files from a mapped drive to a folder on the local drive.

When the batch file is run from the command line, it functions perfectly.

When it's run from Task Scheduler, the XCopy command displays the error:

`Invalid drive specification`

If it matters, the drive is a NAS and is mapped to the computer using local credentials from the NAS (there is no active directory in the network).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this behavior before when trying to backup to a mapped NAS. I don't know why, but it needs a "nudge" to remember that X: drive is mapped to \myserver\myfolder.

Manually, this can be solved by accessing the target folder. Once you "touch" X:, Windows "remembers" it's there. Programmatically (i.e. from batch), you can either try accessing the mapped folder, or maybe even remapping it (using the `net` command) in the batch, before the XCopy command.

Comment: I tried several different ways of nudging.  Finally issuing `net use F: \\Server\Path` (without re-supplying any credentials) did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes very late, but I found another way to circumvent the problem. It seems to be caused by a different context when running from a scheduled task (even if `Run with highest privileges` is selected), rather then from an elevated prompt.

> Configure the `EnableLinkedConnections` registry value. This value
>   enables `Windows Vista and Windows 7` to share network connections
>   between the filtered access token and the full administrator access
>   token for a member of the Administrators group. After you configure
>   this registry value,  LSA checks whether there is another access token
>   that is associated with the current user session if a network resource
>   is mapped to an access token. If LSA determines that there is a linked
>   access token, it adds the network share to the linked location.
>
> 1. Start **regedit**
> 2. Locate and then right-click the registry subkey **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System**.
> 3. Point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
> 4. Type **EnableLinkedConnections**, and then press ENTER.
> 5. Right-click **EnableLinkedConnections**, and then click Modify.
> 6. In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.
> 7. Exit Registry Editor, and then **restart the computer.**

Reference is [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140(v=ws.10).aspx).